# how to start with struts?

Tags: struts

I am new to java can anyone give some ideas about struts and what are the requirements are needed.and where we can download that ?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/, http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsTutorials

Answer (score 1):

Struts is a framework used to build web applications. Its basis is on the Model, View and Controller (MVC) pattern.

The Controller Components: They are made of the Action Classes and the requests are handled by the ActionServlet.

The View: It mainly consists of Java Server Pages (JSPs). This is used to present information to the users and accept the input from them. They are responsible for displaying the information provided by the model components. Its capabilty can be extended using Custom taglibs abd JavaScript.

Model:The model components provides a model of the business logic behind a Struts program. With Struts 2 we can now do simple POJO programming to create this component wihout the need to extend a super class like the ActionForm etc.

The Most Basic implementation you can start with is building a application in which you log in.
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts-login-form.shtml

Just download MyEclipse and create this project. You could use Tomcat which is very easy to configure with MyEclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Guess google will help you in this, I found a link for you to begin -

http://www.j2mesalsa.com/struts/index.php

http://www.exforsys.com/tech-articles/jakarta-struts/your-first-struts-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Struts is a framework used to build web applications. Its basis is on the Model, View and Controller (MVC) pattern.

The Controller Components: They are made of the Action Classes and the requests are handled by the ActionServlet.

The View: It mainly consists of Java Server Pages (JSPs). This is used to present information to the users and accept the input from them. They are responsible for displaying the information provided by the model components. Its capabilty can be extended using Custom taglibs abd JavaScript.

Model:The model components provides a model of the business logic behind a Struts program. With Struts 2 we can now do simple POJO programming to create this component wihout the need to extend a super class like the ActionForm etc.

The Most Basic implementation you can start with is building a application in which you log in. http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts-login-form.shtml

Just download MyEclipse and create this project. You could use Tomcat which is very easy to configure with MyEclipse.